# Retry promise himself after fail in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I would like to retry my request in a promise. I would like launch my refresh if I have always an 401 error as a loop : (if I have 401 loop on refresh until 200)

I tried with this :

```
const request = require('request');
let conf    = require('../conf');

let core_service = require('coreService');

let self = module.exports = {
    get_count_questions: function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request({
                method: 'GET',
                uri: 'http://api/count-questions',
                auth: {
                    'bearer': conf.token
                },
                json: true
            }, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                    resolve(body);
                } else if (!error && response.statusCode === 401) {
                    core_service.refreshToken().then((data) => {
                        console.log('token refresh');
                        return self.get_count_questions();
                    })
                } else {
                    reject(error);
                }
            })
        });
    }
};
```

I tried with just 'self.get_count_questions();' without return, but it's not work. I have not error message, just my app freeze.

I see in my console.log "token refresh", but after my app freeze...

> Edit

I modified with this, It's like better but the refresh token it's very slow. Just before 401, my app stop, and after about 1 minutes 40 seconds, run:

```
else if (!error && response.statusCode === 401) {
    console.log('need refresh token');
    core_service.refreshToken()
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    resolve(self.get_count_questions())
                } );
}
```

My refreshToken function :

```
refreshToken: function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
            method: 'GET',
            uri   : 'http://api/refresh',
            auth  : {
                'bearer': conf.token
            },
            json  : true
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('=====> refresh token <======');
            conf.token = body.data;
            console.log('new Token');
            console.log('=====> end refresh token <======');
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                resolve('Refresh token successful');
            } else {
                reject('Error refresh');
            }
        })
    });
}
```

[image]

If I refresh my token on each request, I have a problem :

```
if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
     core_service.refreshToken().then((data)=> {
         resolve(body);
     });

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to resolve the returned promise. When you resolve using a promise, you basically say, complete this promise with the result of that promise.

```js
var prom = function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('request start')
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('request finish')
      let ran = Math.random();

      if (ran < 0.1)
        resolve('success');

      else if (ran >= 0.1 && ran < 0.98)
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log('retry');
          resolve(prom());
        }, 500);

      else
        reject('error');

    }, 500);
  });
};

prom().then(console.log.bind(console), console.log.bind(console));
```

So you should update your else if block like this:

```
else if (!error && response.statusCode === 401) {
  console.log('need refresh token');
  core_service.refreshToken()
    .then(() => resolve(self.get_count_questions()));
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer ! I updated my code and my post, but I have an error "(node:803) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): null
(node:803) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code."

Comment: @JérémieChazelle Seems like your core_service.refreshToken is throwing an error. Your first edit makes sense to handle the errors from this refreshToken method. This is not a problem with retrying promise. Your code works.

Comment: Thx ! I modified my refresh function ! It's like better but, the refresh it's very very slow. If I use directly the refresh token on all request, the refresh it's very fast. But if I use your code, the negociation to refresh it's slow, I updated my code with a picture. Just before 401, my app stop, and after about 1m40 seconds, run

Comment: @JérémieChazelle Again I am speculationg but the api you are trying to reach probably has a timeout of 90 seconds. So when you have an incorrect token, api doesn't immediately fail but waits 90 seconds to fail. If you own the api you can change this behavior on api side. If you don't, you have to specify a reasonable timeout in your request. See the timeout option of request.

Comment: indeed I have a problem If I refresh my token always, after 1 minutes. Hum... I use Laravel with JWT Token (tymondesigns/jwt-auth) and my conf : 'ttl' => 1, 'refresh_ttl' => 20160, (ttl 1 for the test refresh)

Comment: @JérémieChazelle Like I said, the wait is on the server side and it could be anything. Debug your server side to find out where this 90 seconds block is happening and fix it. This is already a Php question.

Answer (score 3):

You're making a recursive call, but you're never actually doing anything with its promise.  Therefore, your original promise never resolves.

You need to pass the promise from the recursive call (to `refreshToken().then()`) to `resolve()`.

Comment: @JérémieChazelle: No; you should pass the entire promise from `then()` to `resolve()`: `resolve(...then(...))`

Answer (score 2):

Now you almost have it.

However:

```
return core_service.refreshToken()
                   .then(self.get_count_questions);
```

You're returning that to the `request()` callback; that return value is not used.

Instead, you need to resolve your original promise to the new promise from `then()`, by passing it to your original `resolve()` function:

```
resolve(core_service.refreshToken().then(...));
```

Comment: Thx for your answer ! I tried with : resolve(core_service.refreshToken().then((data) => {
                        resolve(self.get_count_questions);
                    })); but I have an error

Comment: You can only call `resolve()` once.  Calling it inside `then()` will ignore failures in the nested promise.

Answer (score 1):

I know that is not optimal solution but it might helps

```
const request = require('request');
    let conf    = require('../conf');

    let core_service = require('coreService');

    let self = module.exports = {
        get_count_questions: function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                request({
                    method: 'GET',
                    uri: 'http://api/count-questions',
                    auth: {
                        'bearer': conf.token
                    },
                    json: true
                }, function (error, response, body) {
             try{
                    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                        resolve(body);
                    } else if (!error && response.statusCode === 401) {
                       throw new Error(response.statusCode);
                    } else {
                        reject(error);
                    }
                 }catch(exc){if(exc === 401){
                            core_service.refreshToken().then((data) => {
                            console.log('token refresh');
                            return self.get_count_questions();
                        })      
                       }

                    }       
                })
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the initial resolve/reject functions after you retried the request:

```
let self = module.exports = {
    get_count_questions: function() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request({
                method: 'GET',
                uri: 'http://api/count-questions',
                auth: {
                    'bearer': conf.token
                },
                json: true
            }, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                    resolve(body);
                } else if (!error && response.statusCode === 401) {
                    core_service.refreshToken().then((data) => {
                        console.log('token refresh');
                        self.get_count_questions().then((data) => {
                          // call initial resolve function
                          resolve(data);
                        }).catch((error) => {
                          // call initial reject function
                          reject(error);
                        });
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        // reject if refreshToken fails
                        reject(error);
                    });
                } else {
                    reject(error);
                }
            })
        });
    }
};
```

You also have to make sure, that the second call actually resolves/rejects and doesn't land in another 401. Because else you have an infinite recursion.

Comment: I tried with your code, but after the refresh, my app stop, don't freeze but just stop

Comment: Did you also add the catch for the recursive call?

Comment: You should also add a catch to `core_service.refreshToken()` and inside `reject`.

Comment: thx for your help, I try your code wit the catch add on refreshToken function

Comment: I have the same problem, my app stop

Comment: I must stop and restart my app and after I have the error : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1):

Comment: Then the promise is rejected somewhere, but the code which uses your function doesn't have a catch method.

Comment: I have an error with your code : the respond is "null"